# How to include public_html sibling folder in a PhpStorm project?

Tags: deployment, phpstorm, remote-access

I have the following site directory structure (on a shared hosting):

```
/home/username/
  public_html/
    index.html
  resources/
    config.php
```

I am trying to set up a new project using the remote deployment in PhpStorm. I'd like to have both `public_html` and `resources` folders accessible, since both contain PHP files. I am confused by what should be the *Project Root*. Logic suggests that my project root is the top level directory containing all my files, i.e. `/home/username/`.

[image: Create New Project: Choose Remote Path]

However if I mark it such in PhpStorm, the next screen (Specify Web Path) automatically maps my web root folder to the project root.

[image: Create New Project: Specify Web Path]

As the result, if I run `/home/username/public_html/index.html` from PhpStorm, it tries browsing to `https://webroot/public_html/index.html`. This is wrong. The web root should be mapped to `/home/username/public_html`. Actually, the very question ("Web path for project root '/home/username'") is invalid, since there is no web path to folders above `public_html`, that's the whole point of putting `resources` there. How should I properly configure folders in PhpStorm?

Comment: Once you create your project .. you may go into Deployment settings and add additional mapping that will do as you need (map your `public_html` folder as `\` for URLs). That's, of course, if you are using your own proper web server (and not PhpStorm's simple built-in one).

Comment: @LazyOne: does it mean I have to accept whatever (incorrect) project creation phase settings, and just set them up correctly afterwards?

Comment: It's up to you. I, for example, do not use this wizard at all  -- just use "Open" (form Welcome screen) and open local root folder -- IDE will create new project for that folder. Then just configure everything else manually (e.g. if it is all remote -- configure deployment (including excluded paths) and download whatever is required from there).

Comment: This is how it can be setup when ready ( http://postimg.org/image/94vvzmuof/ ). My website root is in `web` folder -- you will have to change that to yours `public_html`. This way when you use `Open in Browser` on file inside your web root folder it will be opened with correct URL. Thing is -- such setting is not possible (AFAIK) to setup in that New Project Wizard -- only manually later when project was created.

Comment: @LazyOne, tried, works. If you convert it to an answer, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such setup is definitely possible -- its very common to have website root folder as a sub-folder of the actual project.

As far as I'm aware it is not possible to create such setup right from New Project Wizard -- it has to be done at later stage when project creation was completed.

You need to go into `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment` and add new mapping. Here is an example:

[image]

Here my website root is located in `web` folder -- you will have to change that to yours `public_html`. This way when you use `Open in Browser` on file inside your web root folder it will be opened with correct URL.